# can't convert undefined into an object

Tags: javascript, thunderbird-addon

I am getting the error "Can't convert undefined to object on the line `return hasOwnProperty(prop);` and I simply cannot figure out where the problem lies. I can post more of the code if necessary.

```
getCardProperty : function (card, prop, def) {
    if (typeof def === "undefined") {
        def = null;
    }

    // json synckolab object
    if (card.synckolab) {
        if (card.hasOwnProperty(prop)) // TODO better check for undefined?
        {
            return hasOwnProperty(prop);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and did know why happens, but when I set up correct html code (with table tags and divs correctly closed) I do not get any more this error!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty(prop)` doesn't exist - you need to qualify it with an object name. Just change it to `card.hasOwnProperty(prop)`.

You can simplify it further:

```
if (card.synckolab) {
    return card.hasOwnProperty(prop) || null;
}
```

This will return `true` or `null`. Or you can simplify even further:

```
if (card.synckolab) {
    return card.hasOwnProperty(prop);
}
```

This will return `true` or `false`.